# Finding all the logs that have the same trace id, but only for failed operations

Tags: sumologic

All my logs have a trace id in them (which identifies a single request inside the infrastructure).
Is there any way to search for a keyword, lets say "Error" for example, and get all the logs that contain the keyword "Error", but also, all the log entries that have the same trace id as the logs that matched for error?

Comment: Please share your sample logs.I will share query